# Batch File - Delete Shortcut From ALLUSERS Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, batch-file, symbolic-link, unattended

In Vista/7, if I try to delete a shortcut using the following command -:

```
del "%allusersprofile%\Desktop\MyShortcut.lnk"
```

...Windows sees this folder as empty and doesn't delete the file.

The environment variable "allusersprofile" points to "C:\ProgramData" however "Desktop" is actually a soft symbolic link to the C:\Users\Public\Desktop folder.

The problem seems to be that these soft links are simply Window Explorer shortcuts and are not recognized by cmd prompts or batch files.

The only solution that I can see is to do the following -:

XP:

```
del "%allusersprofile%\Desktop\MyShortcut.lnk"
```

Vista/7:

```
del "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\MyShortcut.lnk"
```

Is there any common solution for both OSes?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such way due to the file structure changes between XP and Vista/7. One way you could achieve this functionality in a script is to get the OS version using `ver`, run it through a series of `if`/`else` checks, and then use `goto` to run the appropriate command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by Garrett in comments of this question, the only solution I see is as follows:

```
SET Version=XP

VER | FINDSTR /IL "6.1." > NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET Version=7

IF %Version% EQU 7  (
 del "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\MyShortcut.lnk"
)
IF %Version% EQU XP  (
 del "%allusersprofile%\Desktop\MyShortcut.lnk"
)
```

One might note that according to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414241/application-data-folder-in-windows-7/3414264#3414264) question, and a [blog post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851567.aspx) by Raymond Chen, a `dir` of `%allusersprofile%\Desktop\<directory>` should give the proper results on both XP and 7, however in my experience it does not.

Answer (score 2):

You didn’t specify a type of script (VBS vs. BAT), but here is a VB script that is system agnostic. Not my script, I pulled it [from this Microsoft site](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-an-Desktop-Shortcut-708e67fa). According to that page it’s been verified to work on Windows 2000, XP, Vista, and 7.

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
'  
' This VB script removes the requested desktop shortcuts 
'  
' Change only the file name (test.lnk) 
' 
' Script created by Holger Habermehl. October 23, 2012  
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
FSO.DeleteFile DesktopPath & "\test.lnk"
```

## EDIT

The above code will look at the specific user's desktop (i.e. Username "john" logs in, the code will look at "C:\Users\john\Desktop\" or "C:\Documents and Settings\john\Desktop"). If you want to check the public desktop, then change the line that reads

```
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```

to

```
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop")
```

But note that depending on the user's privileges and when you run the script, they may get a UAC box asking to sign in as an admin on Windows Vista/7. I'd run the script in a GPO as a computer startup script.

Answer (score 1):

This works in win7.

I haven't been able to try it in XP but I think it should work.

```
    del "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\test.lnk"
```

Save it as a batch file and run it normally. 
If your account doesn't have administrator privileges you may need to right-click and select "run as administrator." You could also open cmd and just type it as a command.

Comment: That command is deleting a different file ... `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` is not the same as `%allusersprofile%`

Comment: It still goes to the desktop though. `%allusersprofile%` is different but I thought `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` might work for what he was asking. @DavidPostill

Comment: One is the desktop for all users and the other is for a specific user. The contents are combined to create the desktop for the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Good advice here which helped with my scenario.

1. I created a batch file to remove the short-cuts

fixme.bat contains the following 3 lines:

```
del "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\gVim 7.4.lnk"
del "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Cygwin64 Terminal.lnk"
pause
```

2. Right-mouse click on the batch file to pop-up the menu.
3. Select "Run Elevated Privileges", enter your password.

Success.

You may also try "Run as administrator".

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Gooofy, thanks for the answer. Does this cover both XP and Vista/7, as stated in the original question?